# Foreign key model in model's __repr__()

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a Artist-hasMany-Suggestion relation in my Flask application (implemented with Flask-SQLAlchemy).

My Artist class looks like:

```
class Artist(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'artists'

    suggestions = db.relationship('Suggestion', backref='artist')
```

And my Suggestion class looks like:

```
class Suggestion(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'suggestions'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    artist_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('artists.id'))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Suggestion %r>' % (self.artist.name,)
```

The problem is, apparently, that there is no `self.artist` defined for the Suggestion model. What can I do to achieve this?

Comment: Why not like this: `Suggestion / self -> artist_id -> name`? + add name to `Artist`

Comment: Because I thought using the `backref='artist'` would make `artist` available as a field in `Suggestion`. Have I misunderstood something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actualy the problem is that `Suggestion` is not necessarily has associated `Artist`. And it's breaking everything. So either check `self.artist` for `None` or impose that it couldn't be `NULL`.

My test code:

```
class Artist(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'artists'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80))
    suggestions = db.relationship('Suggestion', backref='artist')

class Suggestion(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'suggestions'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    artist_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('artists.id'))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Suggestion %r>' % (self.artist.name,)
```

And IPython session:

```
In [1]: from sqlalch import db, Artist, Suggestion

In [2]: Artist.query.all()
Out[2]: [<sqlalch.Artist at 0x3559490>]

In [3]: Suggestion.query.all()
Out[3]: [<Suggestion u'Hey You!'>]

In [4]: Suggestion.query.all()[0].artist
Out[4]: <sqlalch.Artist at 0x3559490>
```

Comment: I've put `nullable=False` for the `name` column in the `Artist` model, and it gives me the same error. I've then added the same constraint to `artist_id` in `Suggestion` and it's the same.

Comment: Do you have suggestions with `artist_id = NULL`? You may try `Suggestion.query.filter(Suggestion.artist == None).count()` in Python console.

Comment: You were right. I was expecting `repr()` to show something for a newly created `Suggestion`, without any associated `Artist`. Thank you for pointing me out.